# Global variables to pull from an associative array/object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, global-variables

I have 50 dots on a page, each individual divs. When I click one, I want to use the ID to pull values out of an array. I can get the ID but I'm having trouble using that value to get stuff out of my array. Perhaps a global variable problem? Not sure. Not even sure if this is the best way to handle multiple clicks that access multiple data. Any help is appreciated!

```
var location0 = {"name" : "Location 1", "image" : "image1.jpg"};

$('.dot').click(function(){
    var thisLocation = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(thisLocation); //Returns "location0"
    alert(thisLocation["image"]); //Returns "undefined"
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/y8x9T/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it like this :

```
var locations = {
    location1 : {"name" : "Location 1", "image" : "image1.jpg"},
    location2 : {"name" : "Location 2", "image" : "image2.jpg"}
}

$('.dot').click(function(){
    alert(locations[this.id].name);
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8x9T/4/)

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).attr("id")` returns a String `"location0"`. If you want to use it you have to get an actual `location0` variable, so you have to replace one of your code lines using `eval()` function. like this:

> `var thisLocation = eval($(this).attr("id"));`

I would however recommend using a new array, where `"location0"` would be a key, then you would just need to access a key with a string like `locations["location0"]` and avoid using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to access it like this:

```
var test = {
    location0:    {"name" : "Location 1", "image" : "image1.jpg"}
};


$('.dot').click(function(){
    var thisLocation = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(thisLocation); //Returns "location0"
    alert(test[thisLocation]["image"]); //Returns "undefined"
});
```

​

edit: this works

Also the reason why it doesn't work for you at first place is because thisLocation is a string, not an object it self, so you need to use brackets to access objects property by passing name. I just wouldn't advice

Comment: This won't work as the variable is shadowed by the pollution of the element ID in the `window`; see http://jsfiddle.net/y8x9T/2/. You should see `[object HTMLDivElement]`, `undefined` as the two alerts.

Comment: @Matt "Thank you" for down voting, but here is a prove that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/y8x9T/3/

Comment: Haha, that's because you saw my comment and changed your code (and changed `var location0` to `window.location`). I would have removed the downvote, but it can stay now.